# Spring Data Rest and java.time serialization

Tags: spring-data

I've a project without Spring Boot, but it uses some spring modules like "spring data" and "spring data rest".

I've some problem with the serialization of the java.time.* fields.
I've found some tutorials like [this](http://lewandowski.io/2016/02/formatting-java-time-with-spring-boot-using-json/) but even if I add the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

and the following code in my RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter

```
@Component public class CvlRepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
    config.setDefaultPageSize(75);
    config.setReturnBodyForPutAndPost(Boolean.TRUE);
}

@Override
public void configureJacksonObjectMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    super.configureJacksonObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_KEYS_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
}
```

}

my actual response regarding a java.time field is like the following

"rateDate" : {
        "year" : 2017,
        "month" : "FEBRUARY",
        "dayOfMonth" : 14,
        "dayOfWeek" : "TUESDAY",
        "era" : "CE",
        "dayOfYear" : 45,
        "leapYear" : false,
        "monthValue" : 2,
        "chronology" : {
          "id" : "ISO",
          "calendarType" : "iso8601"
        }

What I'm doing wrong? What I'm forgetting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here my adapter. Now it's working

```
@Component
public class CvlRepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
    config.setDefaultPageSize(75);
    config.setReturnBodyForPutAndPost(Boolean.TRUE);
}

@Override
public void configureJacksonObjectMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    super.configureJacksonObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_KEYS_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    SimpleModule sm = new SimpleModule("jsr310module");
    sm.addSerializer(LocalDate.class,new LocalDateSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE));
    sm.addDeserializer(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateDeserializer(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE));
    sm.addSerializer(LocalDateTime.class,new LocalDateTimeSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME));
    sm.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeDeserializer(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME));
    objectMapper.registerModule(sm);
}
```

}

I only need to check for timezone(ZonedDateTime fields) and encoding(seems to be UTF-8 is the default) and all will be fine.
Hope to be useful for someone else